# Can INSERT [...] ON CONFLICT be used for foreign key violations?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert, postgresql-9.5

Given

```
=> select * from referenced;
 referenced_id | name  
---------------+-------
             1 | one
             2 | two
             3 | three
```

and

```
=> select * from entries;
 entry_id | referenced_id |      name      
----------+---------------+------------------
        1 |             3 | references three
```

where `referenced_id` and `entry_id` are primary keys.

I want an insert statement for `entries` that skips insertion if either the `entry_id` already exists or the referenced item does not exist. The first is easily done:

```
INSERT INTO entries
VALUES (1, 2, 'references two')
ON CONFLICT (entry_id) DO NOTHING;
```

Is it possible to check for the existence of the foreign key here too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, join your input rows to the referenced table, thereby removing rows without a match on the FK column:

```
INSERT INTO entries(entry_id, referenced_id, name)
SELECT val.entry_id, val.referenced_id, val.name
FROM  (
  VALUES (1, 2, 'references two')
         -- more?
  ) val (entry_id, referenced_id, name)
JOIN   referenced USING (referenced_id)  -- drop rows without matching FK
ON     CONFLICT (entry_id) DO NOTHING;   -- drop rows with duplicate id
```

The UPSERT itself (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`) only reacts to unique violations. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> `ON CONFLICT` can be used to specify an alternative action to raising a unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation error. (See [ON CONFLICT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) below.)

Since the `VALUES` expression is now not attached to an `INSERT` directly, column types are not derived from the target table. You may need to **cast** input values explicitly when operating with non-basic types. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

Comment: That works very nicely indeed, much appreciated. Thanks for the clarification about the `ON CONFLICT` clause too.

Comment: This work if inserting on the same table I try to reference? so something like `INSERT INTO entries ... JOIN entries` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: You can join to the same table in the same way, just make sure the join condition can only match a *single* row. Else you have to use a different technique.

Comment: What about tables that contain different types like timestamps and byte arrays.
Is there any convenient way to use them in
`FROM  (
  VALUES (1, 2, 'references two')
         -- more?
  ) val (entry_id, referenced_id, name)`
instead casting every single of it inside VALUES ?

Comment: @madnan: Here are some techniques to cast fields of a free-standing `VALUES` expression: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860