# Function dosn't return value from insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_create_tagId(tagName text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(
           SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = tagName)
        THEN
            RETURN(SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag=tagName);
        ELSE 
              INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES(tagName) RETURNING id;
        END IF ;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when i run it i get

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

even though i have `RETURNING id`
What should i do/change?

Comment: Which type is tags.id?

Comment: EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = tagName) should be EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE tag = tagName) to satisfy the boolean requirement. I believe the star is causing your error

Comment: The star won't cause an error, but slows down the test. Select * get all and select looks for 1 occurence

Comment: you are overcomplicating things. Just use `insert ... on conflict`. but for your code to work you need a `return` in the `else` branch

Comment: @jeprubio its an int

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thats really cool, didnt know it existed, but i dont see a way of doing "on conflict select", because you cannot return from a 'do'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586793

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the returned ID into a variable, then return that variable in the ELSE branch:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_create_tagid(p_tagnametext) 
  RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  l_id integer;  
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = p_tagname)
    THEN
        RETURN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag = p_tagname);
    ELSE 
       INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES(p_tagname) 
       RETURNING id
       INTO l_id;

       return l_id;
    END IF ;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you have a unique index (or constraint) on the tag column (which you really should have), then you can simplify this:

```
with new_tag as (
  insert into tags (tag) 
  values ('one')
  on conflict do nothing
  returning id
)
select id
from new_tag
union all
select id
from tags
where tag = 'one';
```

The insert won't return anything if the tag exists and thus the final `select * from new_tag` won't return a row, but second part of the union will. If the row did not exists, the final `select from tags` wouldn't see it and return no row.

This will be more efficient and safe from race conditions.

Of course you can put that into a function too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_create_tagid(p_tagname text) 
  RETURNS text AS $$
$$ 
  with new_tag as (
    insert into tags (tag) 
    values (p_tagname)
    on conflict do nothing
    returning id
  )
  select id
  from new_tag
  union all
  select id
  from tags
  where tag = p_tagname;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare new variable and get **tag_id** into it and return. I supposed that id is **autoincrement** or **serial** data type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_create_tagId(tagName text) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
tag_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag = tagName) THEN

        tag_id := (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag=tagName);
        RETURN tag_id;

        ELSE 
              INSERT INTO tags(tag) VALUES(tagName);
              tag_id := (SELECT max(id) FROM tags);
              RETURN tag_id; 
        END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `tag_id := (SELECT max(id) FROM tags);` is a pretty bad idea

Comment: I did not know about RETURNING. Your answer is more advanced. Thank you

Comment: A generated value should be accessed using `lastval()` (or `currval()` if you know the sequence's name). Using `max()` is the least efficient way