# How to avoid explicit casting NULL during INSERT in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am writing python scripts to sychronize tables from a MSSQL database to a Postgresql DB. The original author tends to use super wide tables with a lot of regional consecutive `NULL` holes in them.

For insertion speed, I serialized the records in bulk to string in the following form before `execute()`

```
INSERT INTO A( {col_list} ) 
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (row_1), (row_2),...) B( {col_list} )
```

During the row serialization, its not possbile to determin the data type of `NULL` or `None` in python. This makes the job complicated. All `NULL` values in `timestamp` columns, `integer` columns etc need explicit type cast into proper types, or Pg complains about it.

Currently I am checking the DB API `connection.description` property and compare column type_code, for every column and add type casting like `::timestamp`  as needed.

But this feels cumbersome, with the extra work: the driver already converted the data from text to proper python data type, now I have to redo it for column with those many `None`s.

Is there any better way to work around this with elegancy & simplicity ?

Comment: Do you really need the `SELECT`? In the example you've given, `INSERT INTO A (...) VALUES ...` should be enough. I think Postgres is less fussy about unknown parameter types when there's no query involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting from a `SELECT`, you can attach a `VALUES` clause directly to the `INSERT`, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO A ({col_list}) 
VALUES (row_1), (row_2), ...
```

When you insert from a query, Postgres examines the query in isolation when trying to infer the column types, and then tries to coerce them to match the target table (only to find out that it can't).

When you insert directly from a `VALUES` list, it knows about the target table when performing the type inference, and can then assume that any untyped `NULL` matches the corresponding column.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *need* the `SELECT`, go with [@Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030369/939860).
If you need it (like with a CTE to use the input rows multiple times), there are workarounds depending on the details of your use case.

Example, when working with ***complete rows***:

```
INSERT INTO A -- complete rows
SELECT * FROM (
   VALUES ((NULL::A).*), (row_1), (row_2), ...
   ) B
OFFSET 1;
```

`{col_list}` is optional noise in this particular case, since we need to provide complete rows anyway.

Detailed explanation:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

Comment: Thanks for the technique. I didn't use CTE. But this rowtype casting looks very helpful. I wish I knew it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create json from data and then rowset from json using `json_populate_record(..)`.

```
postgres=# create table js_test (id int4, dat timestamp, val text);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# insert into js_test
postgres-# select (json_populate_record(null::js_test,
postgres(# json_object(array['id', 'dat', 'val'], array['5', null, 'test']))).*;
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# select * from js_test;
 id | dat | val
----+-----+------
  5 |     | test
```

You can use `json_populate_recordset(..)` to do the same with multiple rows in one go. You just pass json **value** that is array of json. Make sure it isn't array of json.

So this is OK: `'[{"id":1,"dat":null,"val":6},{"id":3,"val":"tst"}]'::json`

This is not: `array['{"id":1,"dat":null,"val":6}'::json,'{"id":3,"val":"tst"}'::json]`

```
select *
from json_populate_recordset(null::js_test,
                             '[{"id":1,"dat":null,"val":6},{"id":3,"val":"tst"}]')
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz,  It looks good. but with this json function, I can't figure out how to insert multiple rows in one go without repeating the column names per row.

Comment: @Ben I have updated my answer to include function that will produce rowset in one call: `json_populate_recordset(..)`

Comment: Thanks, but these repeated column names seem redundent, These tables in my case have dozen columns, each priodically with many nulls . the overhead seems a bit high.