# Update column with input from a VALUES expression without explicit type cast

Tags: postgresql, null, sql-update

I'm trying to update a nullable date column with NULL and for some reason Postgres takes NULL as text and gives the below error

```
 UPDATE tbl
 SET
 order_date = data.order_date
 FROM
 (VALUES (NULL, 100))
 AS data(order_date,id)
 WHERE data.id = tbl.id
```

And the error shows:

> [42804] ERROR: column "order_date" is of type date but expression is
>   of type text
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

I can fix this by explicitly converting NULL to date as below:

```
NULL::date
```

But, Is there a way to achieve this without explicit type conversion?

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the explicit cast by copying data types from the target table:

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET    order_date = data.order_date
FROM  (
   VALUES
    ((null::tbl).order_date, (null::tbl).id)
    (null, 100)
   ) data(order_date, id)
WHERE  data.id = tbl.id;
```

This way, you don't have to know column data types.

The added dummy row with `null` values is filtered by `WHERE  data.id = tbl.id`.

Related answer with detailed explanation:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

Comment: What a cute answer! Of course you can also use a type cast in the main query.