# How to know which column has changed on UPDATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

In a statement like this:

```sql
update tab1 set (col1,col2)=(val1,val2) returning "?"
```

I send whole row for update on new values, `RETURNING *` gives back the whole row, but is there a way to check which exactly column has changed when others remained the same?

I understand that `UPDATE` rewrites the values, but maybe there is some built-in function for such comparison?

Comment: perhaps a trigger on update?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some data yourself: 1) create table statement, 2) sample data and 3) the queries that reproduce your scenario. Just to avoid that we misunderstand your question.

Comment: Well it's a typical scenario. update tab1 set (col1,col2)=(val1,val2) returning "?"

Comment: There are ways. How exactly do you `send whole row for update on new values`. Please show your current code. And how does "upsert" play into this. At first, you only speak of "update".

Comment: I think I provided it in previous comment, or you want the original code? It is just the same, but much longer. Upsert through insert or just update - no matter for me, if you have some working example please provide it. I do not stick to method, but solution.

Comment: Please [edit] all defining information into the question. Comments are not the place. The short version is good, as long as the principal problem is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need the pre-`UPDATE` values of updated rows to compare. That's kind of hard as `RETURNING` only returns post-`UPDATE` state. But can be worked around. See:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only/7927957#7927957)

So this does the basic trick:

```sql
WITH input(col1, col2) AS (
   SELECT 1, text 'post_up'  -- "whole row"
   )
, pre_upd AS (
   UPDATE tab1 x
   SET    (col1, col2) = (i.col1, i.col2)
   FROM   input i
   JOIN   tab1  y USING (col1)
   WHERE  x.col1 = y.col1
   RETURNING y.*
   )
TABLE  pre_upd
UNION ALL
TABLE  input;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f49ff4fd11220dd2738bb20a163c2824)*

This is assuming that `col1` in your example is the `PRIMARY KEY`. We need *some* way to identify rows unambiguously.

Note that this is ***not*** safe against race conditions between concurrent writes. You need to do more to be safe. See related answer above.

The explicit cast to `text` I added in the CTE above is redundant as `text` is the default type for string literals anyway. (Like `integer` is the default for simple numeric literals.) For other data types, explicit casting may be necessary. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

Also be aware that all updates write a new row version, even if nothing changes at all. Typically, you'd want to suppress such costly empty updates with appropriate `WHERE` clauses. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

While "passing whole rows", you'll have to check on all columns that might change, to achieve that.

Comment: Well looks like generally (and hopefully safer and easier) this can be done in app code by querying current statement and then with "returning * " compare values in code. I hoped there would be some easier solution...

Comment: @IvanKolyhalov: Doing it in app code simplifies the logic in SQL. **But** you need two round trips to the server if you first fetch update candidates, and then do the actual update. That widens the time window for interfering concurrency. Row locks (or heavier guns) to defend against race conditions have to stay in place (much) longer, possibly hampering performance for write-heavy use cases.