# UPSERT based on UNIQUE constraint with NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, unique, upsert

I have a Postgres table with a unique constraint on multiple columns, one of which can be NULL. I only every want to allow one record with NULL in that column for each combination.

```
create table my_table (
   col1 int generated by default as identity primary key,
   col2 int not null,
   col3 real,
   col4 int,
   constraint ux_my_table_unique unique (col2, col3)
);
```

I have an upsert query that I want to update col4 when it encounters a record with the same values in col2, col3:

```
insert into my_table (col2, col3, col4) values (p_col2, p_col3, p_col4)
on conflict (col2, col3) do update set col4=excluded.col4;
```

But the conflict is not firing when col3 is NULL. I have read about using triggers. What is the best solution to get the conflict to fire please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can find a value that can never legally exist in `col3` (make sure with a check constraint), you could use a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_table (
   col2,
   coalesce(col3, -1.0)
);
```

and use that in your `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (p_col2, p_col3, p_col4)
ON CONFLICT (col2, coalesce(col3, -1.0))
DO UPDATE SET col4 = excluded.col4;
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me. My nullable column was float and -1 was an ineligible value so I used coalesce(mycol, -1). Note the required coalesce statement is repeated in the on conflict for this to work!

Answer (score 6):

### Postgres 15

... adds the clause `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`. Your case works out of the box now:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS ux_my_table_unique
, ADD CONSTRAINT ux_my_table_unique UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (col2, col3);

INSERT INTO my_table (col2, col3, col4)
VALUES (p_col2, p_col3, p_col4)
ON     CONFLICT (col2, col3) DO UPDATE
SET    col4 = EXCLUDED.col4;
```

See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

### Postgres 14 or older

`NULL` values are not considered equal to each other and thus never trigger a `UNIQUE` violation. That means, your current table definition does not do what you say it should do. There can already be multiple rows with `(col2, col3) = (1, NULL)`. `ON CONFLICT` never fires for `col3 IS NULL` in your current setup.

You can enforce your `UNIQUE` constraint with two partial `UNIQUE` indexes as also outlined here:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

Applied to your case:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_col2_uni_idx ON my_table (col2)
WHERE col3 IS NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_col2_col3_uni_idx ON my_table (col2, col3)
WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL;
```

**But** `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` can only be based on a **single** `UNIQUE` index or constraint. Only the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` variant works as "catch-all". See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

It would *seem* like what you want is currently impossible, but there is a ...

#### Perfect solution

With the two partial `UNIQUE` indexes in place, you can use the right statement based on the input value of `col3`:

```sql
WITH input(col2, col3, col4) AS (
   VALUES
     (3, NULL::real, 5)  -- ①
   , (3, 4, 5)
   )
, upsert1 AS (
   INSERT INTO my_table AS t(col2, col3, col4)
   SELECT * FROM input          WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
   ON     CONFLICT (col2, col3) WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL  -- matching index_predicate!
   DO     UPDATE
   SET    col4 = EXCLUDED.col4
   WHERE  t.col4 IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.col4  -- ②
   )
INSERT INTO my_table AS t(col2, col3, col4)
SELECT * FROM input    WHERE col3 IS NULL
ON     CONFLICT (col2) WHERE col3 IS NULL  -- matching index_predicate!
DO     UPDATE SET col4 = EXCLUDED.col4
WHERE  t.col4 IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.col4;  -- ②
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cd8f8dbd934bfefac8e2e23d03405457)*

Works in every case.
Even works for multiple input rows with an arbitrary mix of `NULL` and `NOT NULL` values for `col3`.
And doesn't even cost much more than the plain statement because each row only enters into one of the two UPSERTs.

This is one of those "Eurika!" queries where everything just clicks, against all odds. :)

① Note the explicit cast to `::real` in the CTE `input`. This related answer explains why:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

② The final `WHERE` clause is optional, but highly recommended. It would be a waste to go through with the `UPDATE` if it doesn't actually change anything. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)