# Error "no unique or exclusion constraint matching ON CONFLICT" for composite keys with overlapping columns

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unique, composite-key, node-postgres

I have a table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  tok TEXT,
  sid TEXT NOT NULL,
  aid TEXT,
  hash TEXT,
  qtt SMALLINT,
  p DECIMAL,

  UNIQUE (tok, sid, aid),
  UNIQUE (sid, qtt, hash)
);
```

I want to create a dynamic insert function with node-pg, the query of which looks roughly like this:

```sql
INSERT (tok, sid, aid, qtt, hash, p)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
ON CONFLICT (tok, sid, aid, qtt, hash)
DO UPDATE SET p = $6;
```

and when I try to insert values of `(NULL, string, NULL, int, string, decimal)` (values that match one of the composite keys) it throws this error:

> error: there's no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification.

This has to do less with node-pg but how I made the `INSERT` query itself it seems. My intent is for a single upsert query to handle list items of both "`UNIQUE` types" in case of a conflict, no other questions about composite uniques give a firm answer on how to do it with composite keys with overlapping columns.

Assuming there will only be rows that match either one of the unique keys, what do I do with the insert or constraints to make it work properly? Is there a way to also keep it a dynamic one-query solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DO UPDATE` variant of `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` works for a **single** "conflict target". [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> For `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, it is optional to specify a
> *`conflict_target`*; when omitted, conflicts with all usable constraints (and unique indexes) are handled. For `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, a *`conflict_target`* must be provided.

You cannot conflate columns from multiple `UNIQUE` constraints into one "conflict targget". That makes Postgres look for a *single* multicolumn constraint on all five columns, which is not there and results in the error message you reported.

```
ON CONFLICT (tok, sid, aid, qtt, hash)
```

You can "check" with the `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`, which handles all constraints, including the two you mentioned. But that only suppresses the exception and does not avoid possible race conditions for a later `UPDATE`. There is no clean "one-query solution".

#### Design problem

Your desired workflow is inherently flawed.

If only one of both unique constraints is violated, and you then update the value column, but not the other columns, that makes the resulting state questionable. The row ends up with different (pre-existing) values for the remaining columns which, in turn, will trigger a unique violation for different values for the next `INSERT`. The result of a bulk UPSERT suddenly depends on the sequence of input rows.

Also, **two** rows could raise a unique violation at once. Which shall be updated? (UPSERT is built around the premise to update **one**.) This is a hot mess.

The clean solution would be to have **two separate tables** with **one** PK each.

Or maybe **two mutually exclusive partial unique indexes** for the one table. All columns are **nullable**, except `sid` which is the intersection between both unique indices. That would point in that direction. Is only one of `(tok, aid)` and `(qtt, hash)` `NOT NULL` for every row?

With some luck you run **Postgres 15 or later**, and you can consolidate both unique constraints into one using the `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` clause:

```sql
ALTER TABLE list
  DROP CONSTRAINT list_sid_qtt_hash_key
, DROP CONSTRAINT list_tok_sid_aid_key
, ADD CONSTRAINT list_uni_key UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (sid, qtt, hash, tok, aid);
```

Then all your problems go away.
See:

- [UPSERT based on UNIQUE constraint with NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746862/upsert-based-on-unique-constraint-with-null-values/69747756#69747756)

Related:

- [Use multiple conflict_target in ON CONFLICT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888012/use-multiple-conflict-target-in-on-conflict-clause)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Comment: I think I formatted my question poorly cuz I don't know how to interpret this, so i edited my question to more accurately reflect what my actual issue is. My bad!

Comment: I updated accordingly. You won't get what you ask, but maybe something even better ...

Comment: Works, thank you! Didn't realize `NULLS NOT DISCTINCT` would make more sense for this.

Comment: So it was a `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` case after all. My crystal ball is on fire right now. :)