# Optimize query with null and false checks in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, query-optimization, boolean-logic

Can I make the following query shorter and/or optimal?

```sql
WITH myvars (t_state, t_hv_involved, num_vehicle_hv )
AS (VALUES ('TAS', null, null))

SELECT * FROM safety.crash_summary_view c, myvars 
WHERE jurisdiction = t_state
AND ((t_hv_involved::boolean = TRUE AND c.num_vehicle_hv > 0)
   OR t_hv_involved is null
   OR t_hv_involved::boolean = FALSE)
```

If `t_hv_involved` is `true` then it should filter on `num_vehicle_hv > 0`.
If `t_hv_involved` is `false` or `null`, do not filter.

Comment: You can shorten it by leaving out `= TRUE` and changing `t_hv_involved::boolean = FALSE` to `NOT t_hv_involved::boolean`, but I don't think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
...
AND   (t_hv_involved IS NOT TRUE OR c.num_vehicle_hv > 0)
```

Assuming `t_hv_involved` is type `boolean` as it should, you don't need to cast.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE)

> `boolean` `IS NOT TRUE` → `boolean`
>
> Test whether boolean expression yields false or unknown.
> `true IS NOT TRUE` → `f`
> `NULL::boolean IS NOT TRUE` → `t` (rather than `NULL`)

The complete test case could be:

```sql
SELECT *  -- you really need all columns?
FROM   safety.crash_summary_view c
CROSS  JOIN (
   VALUES
     ('TAS', null::bool, null::numeric)
   ) v (t_state, t_hv_involved, num_vehicle_hv)
WHERE  c.jurisdiction = v.t_state
AND   (v.t_hv_involved IS NOT TRUE OR c.num_vehicle_hv > 0);
```

Note the explicit type declaration in the first row of the `VALUES` expression. I didn't cast `'TAS'` as that defaults to type `text` anyway.  You may want to be explicit and cast that, too.
Additional rows can be untyped literals - but `boolean` values can't be quoted.
See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

Of course, `c.num_vehicle_hv > 0` is `null` while you pass `null` for `num_vehicle_hv`, and the test returns no rows with `v.t_hv_involved IS TRUE`.

Comment: Perhaps you should recommend a conditional index.