# "There is a column named ... it cannot be referenced from this part of the query." How to fix this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, sql-insert

There's a simple table with columns `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`. I want value in `d` to be `a+b` if `c>0` and `a-b` if `c<=0`. How can I do this?

I tried this code and it doesn't work. How can I dynamically insert data in a table?

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,2,3, 
CASE
    WHEN c<0
    THEN a+b
    ELSE a-b
END
)
```

Comment: Could you tell us why you need this, please? It might be better to change your table design. It also might be better to do this in a programming language rather than SQL.

Comment: I have a task to insert data like this and I just made up this example to understand how to hadle with this problem. How can I do it with python, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want value in D (a+b) if C>0 and (a-b) if C<=0. How can I do this?

You can't reference columns in values. Instead, you need to repeat the values. Assuming you're issuing the query in a programming language using bind parameters...

```
insert into my_table(a, b, c, d)
  values(
    $1, $2, $3,
    case
    when $3 > 0 then $1 + $2
    else $1 - $2
  )
```

You can also write a function.

```
--  I want value in D (a+b) if C>0 and (a-b) if C<=0.
create function my_insert(a int, b int, c int)
returns void
language plpgsql
as $$
declare d integer;
begin
  case
  when c > 0 then d = a + b;
  else d = a - b;
  end case;

  insert into my_table ("a", "b", "c", "d") values (a, b, c, d);
end;
$$

select my_insert(1, 2, 3);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/hZTnRqpR).

Answer (score 0):

Working with literal values, you can achieve the same with a subquery:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c,d) 
SELECT *, CASE WHEN c<0 THEN a+b ELSE a-b END AS d
FROM (
   VALUES
     (3,2, 1)  -- input values here, once
   , (3,2,-1)  -- multiple rows if need be
   ) sub(a,b,c);
```

This works without explicit type casts for basic types like `integer` or `text` as the assumed default types for the literals happen to match. You may need explicit data type casts for other data types in a separate `VALUES` expression. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

**More fundamentally**, avoid the problem by **not storing redundant data** in the table to begin with.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  a int
, b int
, c int
--  NO d; will be computed on the fly
);
```

`INSERT` is back to basics:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (a,b,c) VALUES
  (3,2, 1)
, (3,2, 0)
, (3,2,-1)
;
```

The additional column `d` can cheaply be computed on the fly. Typically much cheaper than reading more data pages due to increased storage:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN c<0 THEN a+b ELSE a-b END AS d
FROM   my_table;
```

You might persist the logic in a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html):

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *, CASE WHEN c<0 THEN a+b ELSE a-b END AS d
FROM   my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

If you positively need the computed value *stored* (like when computation is relatively expensive, or you do other things with the column), use a [`STORED` generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) (Postgres 12+):

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD column d int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN c<0 THEN a+b ELSE a-b END) STORED;

SELECT * my_table;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h7RMGXlu)

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a generated column! But in my project, I had a problem with that: I needed a generated column to refer to 2 other generated columns and it causes an error, unfortunately

Comment: @РоманСвирид: I see. There are always exceptions to the rule ... Also added a pure SQL DML solution at the top.